# Selectively redirect to HTTPS using HAProxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy, redirection

I have HAProxy configured with a single front end that accepts both HTTP and HTTPS connections.  All backends are HTTP only.

I would like to force certain paths to use HTTPS (/Login etc) so HAProxy returns a redirect for these paths when it receives a request on HTTP.

Comment: Not knowing haproxy too well, but `redirect` is documented quite well... https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-redirect

Comment: To be honest, there's no good reason to do this. Just serve your entire site via HTTPS. Your clients will appreciate it and you'll get better search rankings. And it's just the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I went for the following which works perfectly in my case:

```
frontend yadayada
  ...
  acl Secure dst_port 443
  acl Login path_beg /login
  redirect scheme https code 301 if Login !Secure
```

Answer (score 0):

For URI's ending on /Login, path_end is probably most appropriate:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606544/haproxy-url-based-routing-with-load-balancing

Your config will then look like this (incomplete, for illustration).

```
frontend http
acl secure path_end -i /Login #matches path ending with "/Login"

use_backend secure_server    if secure

backend secure_server
   redirect scheme https if ! secure
```